# Postfix принимает от одного сервера по 2-5 писем с паузой в 10-15 минут

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, centos, postfix

Получается, что сервер принимает сообщения по 2-5 письма с паузой 10-15 минут. В спам фильтре адресат поставлен в белый список.
Сервер на принимающей стороне Postfix

Comment: В чём вопрос-то?

Comment: @Oxyd у меня почтовик формирует на отправку кучи писем сразу.... бывает такое... так вот почтчовик который принимает письма (он тоже мой), делает паузы с приёмом.... сообственно появляется очередь писем.... на что Zabbix кричит, что большая очередь писем

Comment: @victor-alexeev Ну так сложно сказать, вероятно что-то в конфигах.

Comment: @Oxyd я не могу понять, что лимитирует приём писем

Comment: @victor-alexeev Я тем более.

Comment: @Victor Alekseev Покажите конфигурацию postfix.